# .NET Core Web API: return a custom HTTP status code with Content Type application/problem+json

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

`ControllerBase` contains methods such as `Conflict()` that return a `ConflictResult` object (representing an HTTP 409 response) that is derived from `StatusCodeResult`.  The resulting response body has content type `application/problem+json` and looks like this:

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.8",
    "title": "Conflict",
    "status": 409,
    "traceId": "0HLO99QHFC9QI:00000001"
}
```

There is no in-built method/class for an HTTP 410 response, so I made one:

```
[DefaultStatusCode(410)]
public class GoneResult : StatusCodeResult
{
    public GoneResult() : base(410)
    {}
}
...
public static class ControllerBaseExtensions
{
    public static GoneResult Gone(this ControllerBase controllerBase) // this doesn't give all the problem+JSON attributes
    {
        return new GoneResult();
    }
}
```

However, this gives

```
{
    "type": "about:blank",
    "status": 410
}
```

i.e., the `type` value is different and the `title` and `traceId` fields are missing.

I'd also like to create a custom class for an HTTP 500 response that includes a `message` field with the error message.  I've tried returning `StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)`, which gives me the same minimal `application/problem+json` response as my `Gone()` method; I've also tried returning `StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, message)`, which gives me my error message but formats the response as `text/plain`.

Comment: The two questions you've asked here have different solutions (imo). I've added an answer that addresses the 410 question but the other answer you have (at the time of writing this) addresses the 500 question. I don't see much point in addressing the second question in the answer I gave, as it'd generally just repeat the 2nd half of the other answer (I'd go for not returning explicit 500s but using exceptions and the built-in exception handler stuff, *but that is just my opinion*).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code that generates the `ProblemDetails` response isn't aware of the `410` status-code, so it doesn't have an associated `Link` and `Title` property to use when building the response object. To add this awareness, configure [`ApiBehaviorOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.apibehavioroptions?view=aspnetcore-2.2) in `ConfigureServices`, like this:

```
services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ClientErrorMapping[410] = new ClientErrorData
    {
        Title = "Gone",
        Link = "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.9"
    };
});
```

[`ClientErrorMapping`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.apibehavioroptions.clienterrormapping?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ApiBehaviorOptions_ClientErrorMapping) is a dictionary of `int` (status-code) to [`ClientErrorData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.clienterrordata?view=aspnetcore-2.2). Note that the value I've used for `Link` above does point to the correct section of the RFC.

Comment: Nice. I figured there was some way to do that, but couldn't find anything in the docs or source. Though, granted, I didn't spend a ton of time looking. Out of curiosity, do you have a source for that for future reference?

Comment: @ChrisPratt There's [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#customize-problemdetails-response) in the docs and there's [this](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/release/2.2/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Internal/ApiBehaviorOptionsSetup.cs#L72) in the 2.2 source. There's also the [factory](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/release/2.2/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Infrastructure/ProblemDetailsClientErrorFactory.cs#L20).

Comment: Thanks. I was literally looking at the page from the docs yesterday, and still somehow missed it. Sheesh.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, you have to actually return a `ProblemDetails` response body. I'd have to dig through the code to be sure, but I think ASP.NET Core is doing this via middleware only for particular results. They *say* anything in the 4xx range, but I think that's actually just confined to the built-in result types that return status codes in that range, not *any* result with a 4xx status code. Again, this is conjecture, as I haven't looked at exactly what they're doing, although it's not happening as part of the actual result class.

For your purposes, there's a few different ways you can handle this. You can write your own middleware to catch outbound responses and rewrite them. You can use an custom exception handler. You could simply inherit from `ObjectResult` instead, and then just create a `ProblemDetails` instance yourself and drop that into the base. You could even just return `ProblemDetails` directly from your action (though, that's obviously the least optimal way).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Chris.  For the 500 errors, I ended up implementing a custom exception handler and using the https://www.nuget.org/packages/Hellang.Middleware.ProblemDetails package for the heavy lifting - it's now working nicely.